# MVC3 Cannot attach jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ajax controls. When I attach jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file only I am getting "Error: 'jQuery' is undefined". But when I attach jquery-1.4.4.min.js file too, everything is ok. Why?

Comment: Just don't forget to mark one of the answers that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you load it as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It uses jQuery that is why it is needed. Plugins are built on top of jQuery and uses jQuery as the base. That is why it is needed on every page that has a jQuery plugin.

It's like building a house with no foundation. What will happen? The house will fall apart because there is nothing that it can stand on. The same scenario applies here.

Answer (score 0):

because it uses jQuery... so you must include jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the reference to jQuery library for other jQuery plugins to work. Without jQuery present in your page,you can not run any jQuery plugins.